# Sencha Touch 2 Models associations in json

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have another json response on my one request :

```
{
"user":{"id":"GOLswS44mh8","name":"System Administrator","isAdmin":true,

"ou":{"id":"ImspTQPwCqd","name":"Sierra Leone"},

"ouc":[{"id":"O6uvpzGd5pu","name":"Bo"},{"id":"fdc6uOvgoji","name":"Bombali"}]},

"rootNodes":[{"id": "ImspTQPwCqd","text": "Sierra Leone","level": 1,"hasChildrenWithCoordinates": true,"expanded": true}],

"dimensions":[{"id":"fMZEcRHuamy","name":"Location Fixed/Outreach"},{"id":"fkAkrdC7eJF","name":"Morbidity Age"}
]                           

}
```

I need associate this json respons with model InitialModel .

I understand how to make it for **one Model**

```
Ext.define('App.store.Main', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires : 'App.model.User',

    config : {
        model : 'App.model.User',

        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'data/initial.json'
        },
        autoLoad : true
    }
});
```

So , I can't understand how to convert this JSON to InitialModel which will has this structure :

```
InitialModel:
    UserModel: id , name, isAdmin,
    OuModel: id, name,
    OucModel array [id,name],
    RootNodes array [id,text, level, hasChildrenWithCoordinates, expanded]
    Dimension array [id, name]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify little more regarding where are you stuck or what's the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the configuration for at least your InitialModel class, all of the model classes would help most.

See the Ext.Data.Associations package, namely [HasMany](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany).

Also, if that will not work you can check out the [convert method](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-convert).

Hope this helps, please provide more specific info if you are needing a more specific answer.